# Hierarchical list based on parent_id using C# / LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following List:

```
 List<CommentWithUser> flattened = new List<CommentWithUser>();
```

The Class:

```
public class CommentWithUser
{
   public comment Comment { get; set; }
   public user User { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to create an structured hierarchical list , where each  comment is under its parent_id comment.

I tried using [this extension class](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18) but without success and don't know how to proceed from this point on.

Her's the `comment` class:

```
public partial class comment
{
    public decimal id { get; set; }

    public long user_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime created { get; set; }
    public byte status_id { get; set; }
    public long reply_to_user_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> parent_comment_id { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public int spam_reports { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> root_id { get; set; }
}
```

Note: the comment is multi-threaded = more than two levels structure.
Using: ASP.NET 4.5/C#/Entity Framework 6

Comment: So, the data is already in memory (`flattened` variable) and you just want to change its structure?

Comment: @YacoubMassad yes, it's flattened in memory, and I need to create a structured result.

Comment: is `root_id` the id of the root comment?

Comment: the Id of the root comment is 'id'. The root_id is there for me to be able easily to get an entire thread of a specific comment in the tree. But the root_id will be equal to one of a comment.id enentually. With the root_id I can easily know which top most comment it belongs to instead of running a recursive function that traverse up until it reaches the top most comment and get its Id

Comment: @YacoubMassad The Id of any root comment will be 'id'. but indeed, the root_id is the id of a root comment. A root comment is at the top of the hierarchy, and you can have several 'root comments'.

Comment: Is `id` a string? can you provide the definition of the `comment` class?

Comment: @YacoubMassad id is a BIGINT. The comment object defines a row from the comment table in database. Here's example of comment: id = 1, user_id, 28, parent_comment_id = 10, content = 'this is a sample comment', root_id = '11' (root_id can be null if its the top most comment itself). This means that comment.id = 1 is a child of comment.id = 10 and belongs to a thread that it's root comment is comment.id = 11.

Comment: @IdanShechter It would be much easier if you provide the `comment` class instead of the bullets with field names, but not types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public class CommentWithUserNode
{
    public CommentWithUser Item { get; set; }
    public List<CommentWithUserNode> Children { get; set; }
}

static List<CommentWithUserNode> ToHierarchical(IEnumerable<CommentWithUser> source)
{
    var itemById = source.ToDictionary(
        item => item.Comment.id, 
        item => new CommentWithUserNode { Item = item, Children = new List<CommentWithUserNode>() } 
    );
    var rootItems = new List<CommentWithUserNode>();
    foreach (var node in itemById.Values)
    {
        CommentWithUserNode parentNode;
        if (node.Item.Comment.parent_comment_id == null)
            rootItems.Add(node);
        else if (itemById.TryGetValue(node.Item.Comment.parent_comment_id.Value, out parentNode))
            parentNode.Children.Add(node);
    }
    return rootItems;
}
```

Comment: Get an exception: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

Comment: @IdanShechter so you have some `parent_comment_id` which is not a valid `id` or not contained in the initial list. What do you expect to happen with such items? Put them in a root list? Ignore?

Comment: parent_comment_id can be null, which means the comment is parent itself.

Comment: If it contains invalid Id which is not in the list and it's not null, ignore them.

Comment: @IdanShechter as you may see, the code is checking for `null`. the exception you are getting is from the other branch. so again, what should I do in that case?

Comment: the problem with the code is that it assigns the comment to a place in the dictionary by the parent_id but the that comment with that Id wasn't inserted yet into the dictionary, that's why it throws an exception. Furthermore, the comment structure is multi-levels, not only two levels, so I'm not sure that is can solve the issue, but I am checking the code to make sure.

Comment: @IdanShechter The dictionary should already contain all the id's because that's the first pass. The second pass creates the hierarchy (and it's not 2 level, note it's working with `xxxNode` class which allows unlimited level of hierarchy). See the update.